# Connect to Jenkins Node over socks proxy

Tags: jenkins, ssh

I have Jenkins deployed behind a corporate proxy. I would like to launch the node on AWS and via ssh, so I need to do ssh through proxy.

I have added these lines in `var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/config`:

```
Host <aws host>
ProxyCommand connect -S proxyhost:port %h %p
```

With these changes I can `ssh` to the aws instance manually as the jenkins user from my linux with the command `ssh -i /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/other user@aws`, but I am not able to launch a jenkins node via ssh. I get a connection timeout while connecting to aws.

Comment: I'd be surprised if Jenkins is using the `ssh` client on your system since I'm pretty sure Jenkins has ssh libraries bundled.

Comment: How do i tell ssh library in Jenkins to use proxy and connect to agent. Looking for a way of connecting to node over ssh

Comment: Please add proxy configuration in your jenkins configuration. `Manage Jenkins > Manage Plugins > Advanced` section.

Comment: This proxy configuration what you have mentioned  is only for downloading the plugins, more over its HTTP proxy, for ssh connection to client we user SOCKS proxy

Answer (score 1):

Basing on [this article](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/JenkinsBehindProxy) and [Java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/net/doc-files/net-properties.html) you would have to start your Jenkins with some additional flags, here are the docs:

> SOCKS
>   This is another type of proxy. It allows for lower level type of
>   tunneling since it works at the TCP level. In effect, in the Java(tm)
>   platform setting a SOCKS proxy server will result in all TCP
>   connections to go through that proxy, unless other proxies are
>   specified. If SOCKS is supported by a Java SE implementation, the
>   following properties will be used:
>
> ```
> socksProxyHost (default: <none>)
> The hostname, or address, of the proxy server.
>
> socksProxyPort (default: 1080)
> The port number of the proxy server.
>
> socksProxyVersion (default: 5)
> The version of the SOCKS protocol supported by the server. The default is 5 indicating SOCKS V5, alternatively 4 can be specified for
> ```
>
> SOCKS V4. Setting the property to values other than these leads to
>   unspecified behavior.
>
> ```
> java.net.socks.username (default: <none>)
> Username to use if the SOCKSv5 server asks for authentication and no java.net.Authenticator instance was found.
>
> java.net.socks.password (default: <none>)
> Password to use if the SOCKSv5 server asks for authentication and no java.net.Authenticator instance was found.
> ```

It would most likely look like this

```
java -DsocksProxyHost=some.proxy.host -jar jenkins.war
```

Assuming that you use the documentation defaults.